# Project structure - linking models.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Building a form to submit data to Google Datastore from AppEngine(Python).

I want to move my ndb models out of main.py to their own file models.py. Both of these files sit in the root directory of the project.

Now my model objects are not being created when I test my form with AppEngine(local).

Basically how do I link models.py to the main.py so my handlers can create objects from the models?

My Object is called Consults, the model from models.py is:

```
consult = Consults( consult_date=booking_date,
                    consult_time=booking_time,
                    ...)
```

The error from AppEngine when I submit the form is:

```
NameError: global name 'Consults' is not defined
```

Comment: A separate `models.py` on the side works just fine. Show us an mcv http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your `main.py` imports for the models you need:

```
from models import Consults

consult = Consults( consult_date=booking_date,
                    consult_time=booking_time,
                    ...)
```

Comment: Thanks @DanCornilescu, simple but very helpful ;)